# Problems while uptading from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: updates, 21.04

I was installing Ubuntu 21.04, then some minutes later during the installation process I read in the terminal an error and then noticed that the update is locked and i can't stop it, what can i do?

The error:

```
grub-install: avviso: Internal error.
grub-install: errore: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operazione non permessa.
```

Translations:
`avviso` => `notice`
`errore` => `error`
`Operazione non permessa.` => `Operation not allowed.`

This screenshot may be helpful

[image: Ubuntu 21.04 update]

To reproduce the error just install ubuntu from the advertisement that appear while using the computer, it should work but it's not in my case.
Also, I can't stop the process by using ctrl+c, The only way is a SIGKILL but I don't want to risk to damage my computer permanently, is it safe to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't do the correct thing but while updating there was another window asking me to ignore the part of the process failing, then after all the things were installed the installation program ended by closing unexpectedly and then I have just rebooted the computer. It worked, now I have Ubuntu 21.04 but there is still the problem that something went really wrong.